# Why do I get error while passing value using prepareForSegue?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to send the value of `datePicker` from one VC to another using `prepareForSegue` why do I get an error saying "found nil while unwrapping optional value" here is my code of Sending Class:

```
var dateSender: Date!

@IBAction func sendDate(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {

    dateSender=datePicker.date

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var DateViewController: Viola=segue.destination as! Viola

    DateViewController.HereDate=dateSender

}
```

the code of receiving class:

```
var HereDate: Date?
weak var reminder: Reminder?

@IBAction func `switch2`(_ sender: BEMCheckBox) {

        let name = "hello"
        var time1 = HereDate
        let timeInterval = floor((time1?.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)!/60)*60
        time1 = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: timeInterval)
        let notification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertTitle = "Reminder"
        notification.alertBody = "You need to \(name)!"
        notification.fireDate = HereDate
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

        UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(notification)

        reminder = Reminder(name: name, time: time1!, notification: notification)

    }
```

Comment: Just a tip, start your variables with a lowercase (HereDate should be hereDate, DateViewController should be dateViewController).

Comment: @Hapeki yes I know, I should follow camel case. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have *both* an `IBAction` and a `segue` connected to your date picker?

Remove your `@IBAction func sendDate()` function (and disconnect it from the date picker).

In `prepare(for segue:)`, simply do:

```
    DateViewController.HereDate = datePicker.date
```

Comment: I have other properties too in the `@IBAction func sendDate()`so cant remove it, but I've removed the `dateSender=datePicker.date` from the action but still I get an error in line `let timeInterval = floor((time1?.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)!/60)*60`

Comment: Your time1 variable is most likely nil. Can you print the datePicker.date before you segue? So in your sending VC.

Comment: yes it works fine, If I dont segue it to another VC, the `datePicker.date` works fine

Comment: OK - tough to help you work out your code, if you don't post the code you are using. If you have ***both*** `IBAction` *and* `segue` connected to an action (your datePicker selection, in this case), one will happen before the other. If `prepare(for segue:)` happens first, `dateSender` is invalid. Use one or the other, but not both.

Comment: maybe you can have a look at both the classes https://gist.github.com/raunakstrikha/287eb0d92ef5ef817dc191dfa9fe4f86

Comment: In that code, what happens if you simply delete (or comment out) line 77 of `senderClass`?  `//DateViewController.HereDate=dateSender`

Comment: That helped, I dont know why I had `dateSender` in my class, instead I could've directly done it by what you meant. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I made a demo project to demonstrate how to pass a date with a segue. Clone my project:

https://github.com/Hapeki/Example1

Notice the segue identifier in the storyboard.